# Cheap way of temperature testing my boards

Tags: temperature

I want to make sure my product will work over a large temperature range of -40C to +75C. I can verify on the low end down to about -18C using a household freezer (which is probably good enough) but I'm not sure how to test it on the high end. Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the high end, you could use a hacked sous vide cooker with a PID controller.

http://hackaday.com/2010/11/06/hacking-together-a-sous-vide-cooker/

Comment: Ugh. My college blocks "hackaday.com" as "Hacking/Cracking/Computer Crime"... :(

Answer (score 5):

I've resorted to cardboard boxes with air holes cut into them - allow the product to slowly warm the air inside to the desired temperature and control ventilation to keep it somewhat steady. If more heat is needed, put a power resistor inside the box and use a regulated DC supply to control how much heat it adds to the environment.

Comment: ...And you've never generated any flames?

Comment: Not so far :) Mind you, I usually work on stuff in chassis, and push the temps up to 60C.

Comment: @Kevin - Paper only catches fire above 230°C, remember the novel "451 Fahrenheit". Cardboard may be around that value.

Comment: @stevenvh Any self-respecting switcher usually turns itself off when something goes outside of its SOA (typically 110-130°C) so the risk of cardboard fire is low.

Answer (score 4):

Can you use an oven?  Mine can be set to a low around 75 degrees C.  I've done cheap temperature cycling tests before by quickly swapping a device between my oven and my refrigerator freezer.  I'd just use a TC to measure the actual temperature as the oven readout may not be very accurate.

Comment: I heard that people had success using convection ovens and PCBs for temperature testing.

Answer (score 2):

Heat gun / paint stripper with adjustable temperature control pointed into an enclosure around your PCB works for the high range, and Circuit Freeze will work on the low end (goes down to -62F).

Answer (score 1):

When I was temperature testing an industrial design I used an old refrigerator; cut a hole in the door and used a heater to drive the temp up to 40C. It didn't smell particularly good but I imagine an insulated metal "box in a box" type design would work very well for your 75C test.  Take a look around to see how people make casting furnaces and do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I once made a small oven to dry my photosensitive lacquer PCBs. It was basically a matrix of 1W resistors directly 230V AC powered. I mounted the resistors 1cm above a PCB so that the air could flow freely around them and the heat was distributed well without hot spots. This heater was temperature controlled by a (unfortunately long obsolete) [TDA1024](http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheet/philips/TDA1024.pdf) + NTC temperature sensor.

[image: TDA1024 application]

The TDA1024 can be replaced by a transformerless power supply to feed a comparator.
My thermostat was set at a fixed 50°C, but with a potmeter you can vary the temperature.